# How to get nested type of nested type in C++11

Tags: c++11

If I got the following codes from some 3rd-party code:

```
template <typename T>
class MemberType
{
public:
    using const_ptr = const T*;
};

struct SchemaA
{
    MemberType<int> *m_1;
    MemberType<double> *m_2;

    // more data members that I don't care for
    MemberType<double> *m_3;
    MemberType<double> *m_4;
};

struct SchemaB
{
    MemberType<string> *m_1;
    MemberType<vector<int>> *m_2;

    // more data members that I don't care for
    MemberType<string> *m_3;
    MemberType<vector<int>> *m_4;
};
```

I get different Schema classes which have similar data member, and I want to extract some data member into my own Schema, so I write my class like this:

```
template <typename TSchema>
class MySchema
{
public:
    MySchema(TSchema *schema)
        : m_schema(schema)
    {
        m_1 = schema->m_1;
        m_2 = schema->m_2;
    }

public:
    decltype(TSchema::m_1) m_1;
    decltype(TSchema::m_1) m_2;

private:
    TSchema *m_schema;
};
```

Now I can use MySchema by:

```
SchemaA schema_a;
MySchema<SchemaA> my_schema(&schema_a);
```

In this case, how can I use the nested type of

```
MemberType<T>::const_ptr
```

such as

```
my_schema::m1::const_ptr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use more `decltype`, either:

```
std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(my_schema.m_1)>::const_pt‌​r
```

or

```
class MySchema 
{
    using m_1_type = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(TSchema::m_1)>;
    using m_2_type = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(TSchema::m_2)>;

    m_1_type * m_1;
    m_2_type * m_2;

    // other existing definitions
};

MySchema<SchemaA>::m_1_type /* usage */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use type traits to modify the types, like this:

```
std::remove_pointer<decltype(decltype(my_schema)::m_1)>::type::const_ptr
```

Of course, if you have control over the classes & class templates involved, it might be a good idea to provide nested type names to remove the need for all the `decltype`s.

Comment: `std::remove_pointer<decltype(my_schema.m_1)>::type::const_ptr` ?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes, that will of course work as well.